# Passing external application property values to kubernetes deployments

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have an application.property value which reads like :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<clusterIP>:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=test123
```

where ClusterIP is generated when I create the ClusterIP using the below configuration :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-cluster-ip-service
  labels:
    app: mysql-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

Assuming I get a ClusterIP **10.100.205.156** can I pass the value jdbc:mysql://<**10.100.205.156**>:3306/test dynamically in someway to the deployment yml file before I create the deployment and run mysql deployment in kubernetes.

I am a newbie to kubernetes, please suggest some ideas to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always replace `<clusterIP>` with DNS name of your service `mysql-cluster-ip-service`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-cluster-ip-service:3306/test
```

and let the Kubernetes DNS service resolve the name to the actual IP address. Dealing with IP addresses directly is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Do i need to install Kubernetes CoreDNS or something as a addon to achieve whatever you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store the service name of the `clusterIP` type service in a configMap and inject that configMap in the spring application using [ConfigMap PropertySource](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.0.0.M2/multi/multi__configmap_propertysource.html).

You can take advantage of spring profiles to inject different values based on different environment such as dev,test,prod.

Also spring provides auto reload functional via [PropertySource Reload](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.0.0.M2/multi/multi__propertysource_reload.html) wherein any change in the configMap gets reloaded automatically in the spring application context.

Here is a good [guide](https://blog.nebrass.fr/playing-with-spring-boot-on-kubernetes/) with end to end example.

Comment: Any example github project or a piece of code where it s done will certainly help me. Since i am new to kubernetes dynamically passing clusterip to deploymet files i am not sure how to achieve what you are suggesting.

Comment: the docs link I shared already has code examples.check this GitHub https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples

Comment: @Vikram..have added a link to an end to end example in answer..check it out